# RecyclerView changes it's position value in onBindViewHolder after 2-3 notifyDataSetChanged is called

Tags: android, callback, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

- How to get correct position value.
- Position in onBindViewHolder is changing after notifyDataSetChanged is called 2-3 times in RecyclerView's adapter.
- But Scrolling position is same.

I am setting different view by getItemViewType.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (totalCartSize > productServiceSize) {
        if (position < productServiceSize) {
            return PRODUCT_SERVICE_TYPE;
        } else if (position >= productServiceSize && position < totalCartSize) {
            return PROJECT_TYPE;
        }
    } else {
        return PRODUCT_SERVICE_TYPE;
    }
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}
```

On Clicking Row i have callBackListener for refreshing by hitting service again, but in callBack i am getting wrong value due onBindViewholder wrong position.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof ProductServiceViewHolder) {
        setProductServiceView((ProductServiceViewHolder) holder, holder.getAdapterPosition());
    } else if (holder instanceof ProjectViewHolder) {
        setProjectView((ProjectViewHolder) holder, position);
    }
}
```

- With Regards
- Abhishek

Answer (score 2):

Well, `onBindViewHolder` has nothing wrong with it, it will only do the logic of changing the view values. I think you're problem is you don't fully understand how RecyclerView works.

1. RecyclerView get the total number of items via `getItemCount`
2. For each visible, it get the view type (via `getItemViewType`)
3. For this visible items, they will create a new ViewHolder OR recycle an already created one (based in the type)
4. Set the data with `onBindViewHolder` for each items. So, if you have 4 visible items, the `onBindViewHolder` will be called 4 times. 
   This method will be called for each item when one become visible OR when you tell the adapter that the data changes using `notifyDataSetChanged`. There is nothing wrong with this, I think you have issue with the type.

Btw, you have some other more specific method to prevent the adapter when data change :

```
- final void    notifyItemChanged(int position)
Notify any registered observers that the item at position has changed.
- final void    notifyItemChanged(int position, Object payload)
Notify any registered observers that the item at position has changed with an optional payload object.
- final void    notifyItemInserted(int position)
Notify any registered observers that the item reflected at position has been newly inserted.
- final void    notifyItemMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition)
Notify any registered observers that the item reflected at fromPosition has been moved to toPosition.
- final void    notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount)
Notify any registered observers that the itemCount items starting at position positionStart have changed.
- final void    notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount, Object payload)
Notify any registered observers that the itemCount items starting at positionpositionStart have changed.
- final void    notifyItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount)
Notify any registered observers that the currently reflected itemCount items starting at positionStart have been newly inserted.
- final void    notifyItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount)
Notify any registered observers that the itemCount items previously located at positionStart have been removed from the data set.
- final void    notifyItemRemoved(int position)
Notify any registered observers that the item previously located at position has been removed from the data set.
```

Official RecyclerView.Adapter documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html).

Comment: Hi Hugo, what i really mean is my view is still in same position but i am getting different position value.

Comment: which view ? @abhishek

Comment: @Hugo Gresse  I may have a similar problem here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531900/android-how-to-fix-recyclerview-onbindviewholder.  I would appreciate any thoughts or ideas on how to fix.